# How to lock an overlay?

Tags: cities-skylines

While building things I want to see the overlays from other modes so I can make better decisions.
Can I lock an overlay somehow?

For example:
When building roads I want to see the natural resources overlay.
When zoning I want to see the wind overlay

Comment: Are you asking how to do this in the base game, or are mods OK?

Comment: I was asking in the base game, but mods would do the trick I guess.
Do all mods disable achievements?

Comment: By default, when Cities Skylines detects mods, it automatically disables achievements. There's a mod on the Workshop (if you're using Steam) that re-enables them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This mod](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=465318661) should help you out. It works with zoning and placing roads/buildings. There is an Infoviews button in the top right that toggles the overlays.

Comment: haven't checked it out as I've stopped playing, but mark as answer for future visitors